# Efficiently add numbers to the end of each dimension of a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor x of shape (n, 200). I want to make it shape (n, 218), by appending a tensor of 18 numbers to the end of every "row" of the current tensor. n varies based on the batch size, so I want a way to do this for any n.
As of right now, I have a working solution, but I was wondering if there is a built-in way to do this, I did not see anything in the documentation particularly.
My method is:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F
x = F.pad(input = x, (0, 18, 0, 0)) # pad each tensor in dim 2 with 18 zeroes
for index in range(x.shape[0]): 
    x[index][-18] = nums_to_add # nums_to_add is a tensor with size (1,18)
```

This works just fine, but I was wondering if there is any easier way to do this, without first padding the zeroes.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you could use [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html)

Comment: Would this add to every tensor in dimension 2? It that just torch.cat(x, nums_to_add, dim=2) ?

Comment: Your verbal description makes it sound like you're trying to do something like [torch.hstack](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.hstack.html)

Comment: @CarterKarlFalkenberg First, you only have 2 dimensions so `dim <= 1` since the internal dimensions used are 0-indexed. I believe it would be something along the lines of `torch.cat(x, nums_to_add, dim=0)` since you're stacking the new Tensors vertically.

Comment: I see, I did not realize dim was 0 indexed. However, would this work even if my nums_to_add is a tensor shape (1, 18), not shape (n, 18)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`torch.cat()` is what you are looking for. Here is a snippet:

```
import torch
a = torch.randint(1,10,(3,4))
b =  torch.randint(1,10,(3,2))
print(a)
print(b)
a = torch.cat((a,b),axis=1) # axis should be one here
print(a)
```

##### Output

```
tensor([[2, 5, 3, 8],
        [3, 9, 5, 3],
        [9, 4, 9, 9]])
tensor([[6, 4],
        [1, 1],
        [8, 3]])
tensor([[2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 4],
        [3, 9, 5, 3, 1, 1],
        [9, 4, 9, 9, 8, 3]])
```

Now here is a similar example just used `repeat` to make it same shape in `dim=0` so that we can concatenate it easily. (Trying to follow OP's suggestion exactly)

```
import torch
a = torch.randint(1,10,(5,200)) # shape(5,200)
b =  torch.randint(1,10,(1,18)).repeat((5,1)) # shape(5,18)
a = torch.cat((a,b),axis=1) # axis should be one here
print(a.shape) # (5,218)
```

The only tricky part of the above solution is the `repeat()` part (If you can say it complicated ...), which basically repeats this tensor along the specified dimensions. Check [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html).

Comment: Staying consistent with your example, my "b" would actually have the shape (1,2), not (3,2). Is there a method to duplicate my shape (1,2) tensor into shape (3,2), with all rows being the same, so I can then use the torch.cat method?

Comment: @CarterKarlFalkenberg.: Yes you can. Just tell me the shape of your things, I wil create demo out of it...what shapes do you want to concat exactly?

Comment: Hi. I have a bunch of data with shape (n, 200). The n is the batch size. For sake of example, if you want, you can just say n = 5. Then, I have a tensor of shape (1, 18), where I want to add this tensor to the end of each row n

Comment: @CarterKarlFalkenberg Ok let me prepare one example for you

Comment: @CarterKarlFalkenberg Check it out. It's not that complicated really.

Comment: @CarterKarlFalkenberg Did you understand it? If you find it helpful let me know.